# Unable to locate package php7.3-gd

Tags: php, cakephp, php-gd

I get the error from my cakephp 2.x project:

```
The PHP GD extension is required, but is not installed.
```

I use php7.3 with apache on debian

I search and find

```
apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

I tried this but i only get following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-gd'
```

I searched again, but didnt find a soulution for this problem only for ubunto and nothing else worked. I hope someone could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the appropriate repo added. Try :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3-gd
```

Comment: if i do this following message comes:
/bin/sh: 1: add-apt-repository: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: add-apt-repository is probably not installed, try sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Comment: wow, now even this is broken :/ `Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
`

Answer (score 0):

@Will's answer did not work for me, I then replace the first command from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` to `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and it works for me. So finally I run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php    
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3-gd
```