# php 7.3 Unable to locate package php7.3-gd

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt, php-gd

I'm trying to install the php7.3-gd extension.

When I try to: `sudo apt-get install -y php7.3-gd`

I recieve the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-gd'
```

I tried to update my repo using the following [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57391614/8009034) but to no avail.

Edit: I'm on ubuntu 19.08

Comment: it is recommended add linux or ubuntu tag to the question

Comment: since mid Jun 2019, Ondrej stopped the support of Ubuntu 14.04…

Comment: `apt-cache search php | grep "7" | grep gd` only shows `php7.2-gd` -- maybe you need to wait for it to be added to the main repo. Or you need to add custom repo with the latest package to `apt`

Answer (score 0):

`php7.3-gd` is [available on Ubuntu 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/php7.3-gd).

First, you need upgrade your ubuntu to 19.10:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

And then you can install it:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-gd
```